# Conditional TRIMMEAN

Tags: excel, statistics, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am trying to calculate averages by excluding outliers.  I found TRIMMEAN.

The data set is actually a log of the execution times of a piece of code in some system.

Columns:

- **A:** The execution times
- **B:** Whether the code completed
- **C:** The actually method/function in question (various other methods are also timed)

The following formula determines the average of the ***Complete***, ***Process*** execution times.

```
=AVERAGEIFS(A1:A1000, B1:B1000, "=Complete", C1:C1000, "=Process")
```

**Now I also want to calculate the TRIMMEAN based on the above conditions.**  How can I do this?

I am using Excel 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a **helper column.**  In **D1** enter:

```
=IF(AND(B1="Complete",C1="Process"),A1,"")
```

and copy down.  Then something like:

```
=TRIMMEAN(D1:D1000,10%)
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI

You can do this without a helper column by using the **PERCENTILE** formula within the **AVERAGEIFS** statement.

For example, assuming you wanted to trim the top and bottom 10%, you'd use:

`=AVERAGEIFS(A1:A1000, A1:A1000, "<"&PERCENTILE(A1:A1000,.9), A1:A1000, ">"&PERCENTILE(A1:A1000,.1), B1:B1000, "=Complete", C1:C1000, "=Process")`

Comment: This is wrong. This will calculate the percentiles of the whole sample and he needs the percentiles to be calculated from the values meeting the conditions.

Comment: @N.Pavon Are you sure? I'm fairly certain I tested this before posting.